# register bundle for "jqgrid" in scriptmanager

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, asp.net-4.0, scriptmanager, asp.net-optimization

I am new to bundle and optimization and trying to understand. 
I am creating bundle in site containing **Webform** and **.Net Framework 4.0**. I have created '*BundleConfig.cs*' in which i am creating bundles. it has following code:

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        /// JavaScript Bundles.
        // removed other standard bundles for readability.

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/jqGird")
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")
            );
    }
```

I have also created '*Global.asax*', which contains:

```
<script runat="server">
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        // Registering Bundles
        Sheridan.DPD.WebApp.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // Enabling Bundle Optimization.
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

    }
</script>
```

Now in Master page i am registering the bundle in '*ScritpManager*'

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptMgr" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Scripts>
        <%--Framework scripts--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />

        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jqGird" />

        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <%--Site scripts--%>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

It is giving me following error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'jqGird' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'.

So what is it that I am doing wrong? as other Bundles are working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to register all of your `scripts` together as `jqGird` using [ScriptManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jqGird", new ScriptResourceDefinition
{
   Path = "~/Bundles/jqGird", 
});
```

You can also refer to [ASP.NET 4.5 ScriptManager Improvements in WebForms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/09/21/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms.aspx)

Comment: hi, Thanks. i was able to resolve error by putting your code in 'Application_Start' in global.asax.